# Is there a way to strip a library from all unused parts and defines, automatically?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, esp32, library, ide

Say you want to investigate part of the code you use from a rather large library, but it's buried between all kinds of #defines and classes etc, that you're never gonna use in your code.
Is there a tool for stripping those unused/unnecessary parts away (like the (pre-)compiler), without converting it to machine language? That would make it much easier to see what happens in the code, and what code does what. Would be a great learning tool imho.

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question but... [the command `avr-nm` can tell you how much flash is being used by each function or method](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/12684/7508).

Comment: Good to know! I'll check the memory list from my code. Does it show unused functions that don't take any space once compiled? Saw a grep reference in there too, nostalgia hits... Man, I was pretty handy with grep and sed once. Could've probably stripped the defines that way.

Comment: `avr-nm` works on the compiler output: it cannot see the stuff that was removed or optimized away by the compiler. Inlined functions won't be shown either, as they become part of the functions that embed them (typically `setup()` and `loop()` get inlined into `main()`). You may get more relevant output if you tweak the compiler options to remove link-time optimization (-flto), as this tends to make the compiler very aggressive at inlining.

Comment: you are locking for the -E parameter of the compiler which produces C++ source code after preprocessor?

Comment: @Juraj Maybe. That sounds more like it.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that "organizes" all sources for you to quickly navigate through it? Then of course the Arduino IDE is not the right one. You might want to try other IDEs, perhaps augmented with Arduino specific plugins, or specifically designed tools. And of course you need all the source files of the library in question, which is not the usual case.

Comment: I'll try Visual Studio Code see what I can find. Got it already for websites and javascript and there is quite a lot of options there.

Comment: Yes! I found a cool tool to strip the #ifdef and #define stuff: [Coan](https://coan2.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=about) *the C preprocessor chainsaw*. Off to investigate ;)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is called in optimization mode (it is even possible to specify how aggressive it will optimize). It will remove all variables and functions, that are not used in your code. Also it can replace variables that never change with literals to make the code smaller. That's already what is happening and you don't need to worry about that.

About the `#define`s: Everything with a # at the start is interpreted by the preprocessor. That means, that these things are done even before the compiler gets to see the code. Lets say you define a pin number via `#define pin 6`, then the preprocessor will replace any mentioning of `pin` with `6` in the code, before it hands the result over to the compiler. The compiler will never see any defines.

I'm not able to tell you, how the compiler optimizes the code. That's probably very complex. Though the avr-gcc compiler is opensource, so if you really want to learn what it does, you can always analyze its source code.

---

> I thought if a compiler can be smart enough to strip all unused variables and functions away and convert what's left in machine language

While I don't know much about how the optimization works, I don't think that it happens in that order. I find it very unlikely, that the compiler would optimize the C++ code. Though it might do that at the assembler level (since avr-gcc first converts the C++ code to assembler and then compiles to machine code). Searching in the assembler code equivalent of the C++ code isn't a real option either.

You are probably stuck with a full text search function of a program of your choice. Most OSs will also provide that function out of the box. I know, that you can search all files of a directory for a term from the Windows explorer. On systems like Ubuntu/Debian/CentOS and similar you can use the `grep` command in recursive mode to search for a term. On Mac you can probably also use `grep`.

Comment: Re “_post processor_”: you mean “preprocessor”.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Oh, thanks. Definitely had preprocessor in my head when writing this XD

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I knew the compiler takes care of all that but I'd like to be able to 'quickly' look at a specific code blok (still c++, not compiler code) without it being scattered all around in a library of other functions and methods. I thought if a compiler can be smart enough to strip all unused variables and functions away and convert what's left in machine language, maybe there also is a tool that only strips but doesn't convert. It would be easier to learn how certain parts work that way. Bit of wishful thinking maybe ;)

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I understand better. I added to my answer, though my answer to that part is basically just no

Comment: I clarified my original question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't quite work like that. It compiles each individual .cpp file into an object file (the .ino file becomes a .cpp file after a bit of pre-processing). I have [an answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13178/classes-and-objects-how-many-and-which-file-types-do-i-actually-need-to-use-the/13182#13182) about the exact process the compiler uses there.

The libraries are also collections of .cpp files which also get turned into object files.

Optimization of unused variables would occur at that point. In other words, the compiler can optimize one compilation unit (one source file) because it can see what parts are used and what are not.

Then the linking phase commences which joins all the object files together, looking for places where a function in a library is called. So for example if you call `Serial.begin()` somewhere, then the linker will try to find an object file which implements that.

The linker is smart enough to not include code that is not required, so for example, if you never called `Serial.begin ()` then it would not copy in that part of the Serial library.

In the process of doing that it resolves "jumps" and subroutine calls, so that your calls to library functions end up pointing to the place in the program memory where it has put them.

Because this is done at a late stage (after the source has been compiled) you don't really ever have a copy of the source "as linked".

However what you **can** do is disassemble the object file which gives you the machine code that has actually made it to the final executable. Done properly it will also include the lines of source (C++) code that generated each batch of assembler lines.

If you turn on "verbose compiling" you should see near the end of the compilation output an "ELF" file, and you can then send that to avr-objdump to turn it back into assembler:

```
avr-objdump -S xxx.elf
```

It's not great, if you aren't used to assembler, but it gives you a clue as to what made it into the executable file, and where. For a single line of C++ code you might see something like this:

```
    reg = portModeRegister(port);
 310:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
 312:   88 0f           add r24, r24
 314:   99 1f           adc r25, r25
 316:   fc 01           movw    r30, r24
 318:   e8 59           subi    r30, 0x98   ; 152
 31a:   ff 4f           sbci    r31, 0xFF   ; 255
 31c:   a5 91           lpm r26, Z+
 31e:   b4 91           lpm r27, Z+
```

Answer (score 0):

The -E command for gcc generates preprocessed C and CPP source.

I didn't find a way to integrate it into the Arduino build process. Only thing I could do was edit platform.txt and change the compile command so it generates the preprocessed cpp of a compilation unit instated of .o files. Then linking failed of course.

The produced cpp was I think less readable than the original because it contained many generated comments and original line number instructions.

the changed cpp recipe in platform txt:

```
recipe.cpp.o.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.cpp.cmd}" {compiler.cpp.flags} -mmcu={build.mcu} -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} {compiler.cpp.extra_flags} {build.extra_flags} -E {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}.cpp"
```

I added the -E flag and .cpp file extension for the -o option value

You can see the result in the temporary build folder. You can get the location of that folder from the IDE console when you build the sketch with Verify. (you may need to turn on the verbose compile in Preferences).

Comment: Thanks, I will need to have a good look at all that to see if I can figure it out. Haven't done it before. Is this all command line? Got a Mac nowadays (pfff, still getting used to it) havent touched a terminal yet.

Comment: no command line. it is a command used by the IDE to build the sketch for upload. you have to change it in platform.txt and it will generate the preprocessed cpp instead of creating the hex for upload

Comment: Cool. Gonna check it out soon.